# How to make a JavaScript validation on WordPress Gutenberg Editor Metabox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a custom taxonomy `date` for a custom post type `announcement` on the new version of **WordPress** with **Gutenberg**.

I need this taxonomy to be a mandatory field to publish the post, and I already tried with

```
<input type="date" required>
```

and it did not work, now I am struggling to validate that input with class "requireMe".

So what I tried to do is to capture the `Publish Post` button with JavaScript and disable it either this input was already set or not.

My first problem here was that I never could capture this button because it is not part of the actual DOM, so I already notice there is a new way to do this through the API but I cant find a proper documentation to do so.

All I need is to make this validation.

[as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnlbP.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Editor store](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/store/actions.js) and dispatch an event which disables saving the post until you unlock it again.

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving( 'my_lock_key' );
```

to disable the lock, call:

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving( 'my_lock_key' );
```

You could also optionally dispatch a notice that shows at the top of the editor.

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).removeNotice('LOCK_NOTICE');
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createErrorNotice( 'Please enter a date to continue.', { id: 'LOCK_NOTICE',isDismissible: true} ) ;
```

Comment: Hi again, I am pretty sure the answer you give me is the right one, but I am having a little issue now with understanding how to use 'my_lock_key' as you provide in your answer.
I am new on this WordPress API experience and I have no idea how do I really should handle that parameter or what is it. Could you please detail a little more about it? Thanks
PS: the notice works perfect.

Comment: lockPostSaving takes one parameter, lockName, which is just a key/name you define. You will need to use that same name to unlock it. Presumably, if post saving is locked by some other key/name, you would not be able to unlock it with your key/name.